# How to install jsonpickle in Linux?

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I'm now attempting to program in python on Linux. I am using Linux Mint 15 "Olivia" with Cinnamon desktop. I'm also using python 3.3 now. Being new to Linux, I am unable to find anything regarding getting jsonpickle to work. If someone would be kind enough to post instructions for installing jsonpickle in Linux, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which linux? Why not just pip install jsonpickle ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I could use pip install in Linux. I am using Linux Mint 15 Gnome with cinnamon desktop, 64 bit. I will give pip install jsonpickle a try and post whether or not I can get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can use `pip` or `easy_install`:

```
pip install jsonpickle
easy_install jsonpickle
```

Or the standard method of your distributive (`apt-get install` and so on) if the package is avaiable in the repository.

Comment: okay was able to do pip install jsonpickle. However, it does not work for python 3.3. I get an error in IDLE saying the following:                                                              Python 3.3.1 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:29:01) 
    [GCC 4.7.3] on linux
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
    >>> import jsonpickle
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import jsonpickle
    ImportError: No module named 'jsonpickle'
    >>>

Comment: @JohnBobSmith: What does it say?

Comment: @JohnBobSmith: May be you have several versions of python, and the module was installed for another one. How many pythons do you have?

Comment: I have python 2.7.4 (linux default I believe) and then python 3.3.1 which is what I want to program in. I can import it in python 2.7 IDLE, and not in the python 3.3 IDLE. How do I install jsonpickle for python 3.3?

Comment: @JohnBobSmith: try to run `pip-3.3 install jsonpickle`

Comment: That worked! I also had to install python 3 setup tools and python 3 pip via the terminal. Topic solved!